# Concurrent Usage of Function

Tags: postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I have a function called "ChallanNoGenerator" which created sequential number with combination with other columns.

This function is called from multiple other functions, the problem is that at concurrent call it generate duplicate "ChallanNo"

```
-- DROP FUNCTION "Fee"."ChallanNoGenerator"(uuid);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Fee"."ChallanNoGenerator"(
    admissionformid uuid)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$


declare "ChallanNumber" TEXT;
        "CampusCode" TEXT;
        "SessionCode" TEXT;
        "BusinessUnitCode" TEXT;
        "ChallanNumberEx" TEXT;

        BEGIN

        SELECT 
            CONCAT(bu."DigitCode", cm."DigitCode"), sn."FullName" INTO "CampusCode", "SessionCode"
        FROM 
            "Admission"."AdmissionForm" AS af, 
            "Setup"."CampusProgramLink" AS cpl, 
            "Setup"."ProgramDetails" AS pd, 
            "Setup"."Campus" AS cm,
            "Setup"."SubCity" AS sc, 
            "Setup"."City" AS ct,
            "Setup"."Institution" AS ins,
            "Setup"."Session" as sn,
            "Setup"."BusinessUnit" AS bu
        WHERE
            af."CampusProgramId" = cpl."CampusProgramId"
            AND pd."ProgramDetailId" = cpl."ProgramDetailId"
            AND cpl."CampusId" = cm."CampusId"
            AND cm."SubCityId" = sc."SubCityId"
            AND sc."CityId" = ct."CityId"
            AND cm."InstitutionId" = ins."InstitutionId"
            AND cpl."SessionId" = sn."SessionId"
            AND af."AdmissionFormId" = admissionformid;
        --  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;       
    SELECT ((RIGHT(COALESCE(MAX("ChallanNo"), '000000'), 6)::INT4) + 1) INTO "ChallanNumber" FROM "Fee"."StudentChallan" 
    WHERE "ChallanNo" LIKE "CampusCode" || "SessionCode" || '%';

    SELECT ((RIGHT(COALESCE(MAX("ChallanNo"), '000000'), 6)::INT4) + 1) INTO "ChallanNumberEx" FROM "Fee"."StudentChallanEx" 
    WHERE "ChallanNo" LIKE "CampusCode" || "SessionCode" || '%';


    IF (("ChallanNumber"::INT4) < ("ChallanNumberEx"::INT4)) THEN
       "ChallanNumber" := "ChallanNumberEx";
    END IF;

    IF(LENGTH("ChallanNumber") = 1) THEN
        "ChallanNumber" := '00000' || "ChallanNumber";
    ELSIF(LENGTH("ChallanNumber") = 2) THEN
        "ChallanNumber" := '0000' || "ChallanNumber";
    ELSIF(LENGTH("ChallanNumber") = 3) THEN
        "ChallanNumber" := '000' || "ChallanNumber";
    ELSIF(LENGTH("ChallanNumber") = 4) THEN
        "ChallanNumber" := '00' || "ChallanNumber";
    ELSIF(LENGTH("ChallanNumber") = 5) THEN
        "ChallanNumber" := '0' || "ChallanNumber";
    END IF;

    RETURN "CampusCode" || "SessionCode" || "ChallanNumber";
END

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION "Fee"."ChallanNoGenerator"(uuid)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

this is the first function that I have created to generate challan no.

Now I have modify it with

```
-- DROP FUNCTION "Fee"."ChallanNoGenerator"(uuid, uuid);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Fee"."ChallanNoGenerator"(
    admissionformid uuid,
    studentchallanid uuid)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$


declare "ChallanNumber" TEXT;
        "CampusCode" TEXT;
        "SessionCode" TEXT;
        "BusinessUnitCode" TEXT;
        "ChallanNumberEx" TEXT;

        BEGIN       
        SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(1982);

        SELECT 
            CONCAT(bu."DigitCode", cm."DigitCode"), sn."FullName" INTO "CampusCode", "SessionCode"
        FROM 
            "Admission"."AdmissionForm" AS af, 
            "Setup"."CampusProgramLink" AS cpl, 
            "Setup"."ProgramDetails" AS pd, 
            "Setup"."Campus" AS cm,
            "Setup"."SubCity" AS sc, 
            "Setup"."City" AS ct,
            "Setup"."Institution" AS ins,
            "Setup"."Session" as sn,
            "Setup"."BusinessUnit" AS bu
        WHERE
            af."CampusProgramId" = cpl."CampusProgramId"
            AND pd."ProgramDetailId" = cpl."ProgramDetailId"
            AND cpl."CampusId" = cm."CampusId"
            AND cm."SubCityId" = sc."SubCityId"
            AND sc."CityId" = ct."CityId"
            AND cm."InstitutionId" = ins."InstitutionId"
            AND cpl."SessionId" = sn."SessionId"
            AND af."AdmissionFormId" = admissionformid;
        --  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;       
    SELECT ((RIGHT(COALESCE(MAX("ChallanNo"), '000000'), 6)::INT4) + 1) INTO "ChallanNumber" FROM "Fee"."StudentChallan" 
    WHERE "ChallanNo" LIKE "CampusCode" || "SessionCode" || '%';

    SELECT ((RIGHT(COALESCE(MAX("ChallanNo"), '000000'), 6)::INT4) + 1) INTO "ChallanNumberEx" FROM "Fee"."StudentChallanEx" 
    WHERE "ChallanNo" LIKE "CampusCode" || "SessionCode" || '%';

    IF (("ChallanNumber"::INT4) < ("ChallanNumberEx"::INT4)) THEN
       "ChallanNumber" := "ChallanNumberEx";
    END IF;

    SELECT CONCAT("CampusCode", "SessionCode", LPAD("ChallanNumber", 6, '000000')) INTO "ChallanNumber";
    UPDATE "Fee"."StudentChallan" SET "ChallanNo" = "ChallanNumber" WHERE "StudentChallanId" = studentchallanid;

    RETURN CONCAT('Challan No: ', "ChallanNumber", ' has been generated successfully');
END

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION "Fee"."ChallanNoGenerator"(uuid, uuid)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Can any one with good experience to achieve what I want